# Should I use attach-daemon or smart-attach daemon to autostart celery with UWSGI (and easily update the tasks)

Tags: django, server, celery, uwsgi

First off - I am aware UWSGI suggest using `smart-attach-daemon`

from: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AttachingDaemons.html

```
Managing celery:

[uwsgi]
master = true
socket = :3031
smart-attach-daemon = /tmp/celery.pid celery -A tasks worker --pidfile=/tmp/celery.pid
```

However, it seems when I push updates to the server, Celery tasks are not updated - to make this happen it seems I have do issue `killall celery` - which it seems would be practically automated by using `attach-daemon` to start it instead?

Am I missing something here, is there a better solution than either killing celery instances, or using `attach-daemon` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better use `attach-daemon`, because `smart-attach-daemon` means that you will manage your smart daemon restarting on your own.

Since uwsgi 2.0 there are also ['attach-daemon2'](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AttachingDaemons.html#attach-daemon2) which have `touch` option.

Comment: Accepting answer - as it is what I ended up doing, but still does not explain why celery docs suggest `smart-attach-daemon`

Comment: I did not found it in celery docs https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=smart-attach-daemon%E2%80%8C&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: My bad - I mean UWSGI docs, linked above ( http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/AttachingDaemons.html )

Comment: May be because celery can catch HUP signal for restarting (http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#restarting-the-worker) and you can send it on your own. But IMO it is much simpler to restart it along with main process, like django.

Comment: @Chozabu “This (`smart-attach-daemon`) is the best choice for processes requiring longer persistence, and for which **a brutal kill** could mean loss of data such as a database.” So it implies that the `attach-daemon` involves a brutal kill which may lead to interruption of Celery tasks (instead of a warm shutdown which waits for the completion of running tasks and then exits).

Comment: @Rockallite That should probably be a direct answer, instead of a comment?

Comment: It depends on your goal. `smart-attach-daemon` will not restart your celery daemon at all. `attach-daemon` will brutally restart your daemon thus it could break processed task. With `attach-daemon2` (uwsgi > 2.0) you could specify touch=<some file>, stopsignal=15, reloadsignal=1 and uwsgi will send appropriate signals to celery in case of <some file> modification and uwsgi restarting or stopping.